# Storefront function not outputting correctly

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I'm working on a problem that's making me create an object and two functions in order to create a mock storefront for an SEO site. The directions are below:

1. Create an object named product, with the following 3 properties. 
   Make up the values for the properties, just make sure the inventory is a whole number (it's the number of that product currently in stock) and unit_price is a floating point number like 45.99
   -- name
   -- inventory
   -- unit_price
   before moving to the next step, make sure you've created the object correctly by logging it to the console like this: console.log(product)
2. Create a function named addInventory(). The function should accept 2 parameters -- the product object, and the number to add to the inventory. The function adjusts the product object's inventory property by adding the number passed into the function. 
   // For example, if the inventory of the product is currently 2, calling addInventory(product, 3) will set the value of inventory to 5
   /* Add a console.log() message to the function that includes a message that looks something like this:
   "3 chairs added to the inventory"
   In this example, "chair" is the name of the product.

---

I believe that I've created an object correctly, but the function is off. I've tried adjusting the parameters and the product inventory stays the same @ 6; Given the arguments I passed, it should be 10. I've tried to add the numOfProducts and the product inventory, to no avail. Instead, it's just printing out 6. I would really appreciate any help you can provide. 
Thanks

```js
var product = {
  name: "Skull Candy Headphones",
  inventory: 6,
  unit_price: 49.99
}

function addInventory(product, numOfProducts) {
product.inventory + numOfProducts;
console.log(numOfProducts + " "+ product.name + ' added to inventory');
}

addInventory(product, 4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to add `product.inventory + numOfProducts` and then set the value of `product.inventory`?

You are doing the math part correctly (adding `product.inventory + numOfProducts`) but you are **not actually setting the value of the result**

You need to do this:

`product.inventory = product.inventory + numOfProducts;`

```js
var product = {
  name: "Skull Candy Headphones",
  inventory: 6,
  unit_price: 49.99
}

function addInventory(product, numOfProducts) {
product.inventory = product.inventory + numOfProducts;
console.log(numOfProducts + " "+ product.name + ' added to inventory. product.inventory is ' + product.inventory);
}

addInventory(product, 4);
```